# WCF client response array always return null

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, soap

I have WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.3-atlassian-1. And client that was generated from .wsdl file with svcutil.exe /t:code file.wsdl /n*,Company /serializer:XmlSerializer

The problem is that all array fields in the response are always null. So the idea is to intercept SOAP message in IClientMessageInspector and change it to propper soap message array format. It works fine, except the part with SOAP message deserialization. I just can't manage to create a valid SOAP message for WCF, though XML Serializer is accepting it.

The whole issue is the same as in this question: https://forums.asp.net/t/1994532.aspx?Array+in+WCF+Response+is+null

It is fully described in this forum, so I don't put any code here. But ready to provide any additional information that can help.
Is there any solution for this? Will appreciate any help and ideas.

Comment: Try generating a client from wsdl endpoint using MSVS2019.

Comment: @HirasawaYui Server using is x.509 certificate authentication. So when I trying to add WebReference in VisualStudio(2015-2019) it shows me the confirm certificate  dialog, and then it actually gets wsdl from the server (so the certificate is valid) but then showing this error:
There was an error downloading 'https://xxxx.xxxxx.com:8888/xxxx/xxxx/ServiceName?wsdl/$metadata'.
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Comment: Found a solution. I switch some functions into DataContractSerializer serializer and completely rewrite incoming SOAP messages.  I just gave up to make it in XML serializer.